# In Zephaniah 2:11, what people is this verse referring to?

Tags: worship

Zephaniah 2:11 says,

> The Lord will be awesome to them, For He will reduce to nothing all the gods of the earth; **people** shall worship Him, Each one from his own place, indeed all the shores of the nations.

To what people is this verse referring to?

Comment: Welcome to the group Christina and congratulations on a clear, well formatted question on your first try! If you haven't done so already please review the Tour and Help pages to get the lay of the land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "people" does not actually appear in the verse. It is implied by the context. So translators treat the issue in various ways: "they" shall worship, "people" shall worship, "the nations" shall worship, "every man" shall worship, etc.

What is quite clear is that the prophet is referring to gentiles, which is the actual word (goyim) translated as "nations" above. So he means gentiles. It is implied that people all over the world are involved, although the author's concept of the world was limited, compared to how we conceive of the idea today.

[Interlinear version of Zeph. 2:11](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/zephaniah/2-11.htm)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your very clear answer, and for tying it in with the actual Hebrew word (goyim). My inclination was that it meant exactly as you said, but your answer settled it for me! Thank you!